# In how many ways can a sequence not converge?

Tags: real-analysis

If $a_n$ is a sequence that does not converge it may be that it is not bounded, for example $a_n = n$, or it may be that it is alternating $a_n = (-1)^n$. Are there any more way in which a sequence can ''not converge''?

Note: my question is about the real numbers $\mathbb R$.

The reason why I am thinking about this: I am trying to prove that if $a_n$ is a bounded sequence such that every convergent subsequence converges to the same limit $L$ then $a_n$ also converges to $L$. If $a_n$ is itself a convergence sequence then it is clear that it also converges to $L$. Therefore, it is enough to show that $a_n$ itself converges. My idea is to use proof by contradiction: assume $a_n$ does not converge but every subsequence which converges converges to $L$. I stuck with how to get the contradiction.

Comment: This might help: consider the sequence the equals $1/n+1$ for odd $n$ and $-(1/n+1)$ for even $n$. Notice that it keeps getting "closer and closer" to a "central value" (namely $0$), but nonetheless fails to converge. Try plotting it if you cannot see the sequence easily in your mind.

Comment: Are you considering sequences of real numbers? (Things are different in other spaces, $\mathbb{Q}$ for example.)

Comment: @user18921 I have not plotted it yet but the odd subsequence converges to $1$ and the even subsequence converges to $-1$, right? So what do you mean by it gets closer to $0$? I am confused because it seems to be the case that $a_n \in (-1,1)^c$ so they never get closer to $0$ than distance $1$?

Comment: Yes you're correct, the terms of the sequence remain a distance strictly greater than $1$ from the point $0$. In other words, $a_n \in [-1,1]^c.$ However, the sequence keeps getting "closer" to $0$, in the sense that $d(a_{n+1},0) < d(a_n,0)$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, where by $d(x,y)$ I mean the distance between $x$ and $y$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A sequence of real numbers can fail to converge in only one way: it is not a Cauchy sequence.

It can fail to be a Cauchy sequence by being unbounded, or by "oscillating" between two bounding values (possibly over- or undershooting, but by diminishing amounts). An oscillating sequence has subsequences converging to either of the bounding values (the limes superior, $\limsup$ and the limes inferior, $\liminf$), and possibly to (all) values in between.

In $\mathbb{R}$, the Bolzano-Weierstraß theorem asserts that every bounded sequence has a convergent subsequence (it has many, of course).

So in your situation, your bounded sequence $(a_n)$ has a subsequence $(a_{n_k})$ converging to some real number $A$.

If not the entire sequence converges to $A$, there is an $\varepsilon > 0$ and a subsequence $(a_{n_m})$ such that

$$\lvert a_{n_m} - A\rvert \geqslant \varepsilon$$

for all $m$. Then the subsequence $(a_{n_m})$ is also bounded, hence has a convergent subsequence ...

Comment: Thank you! Could you say something more about ''by diminishing amounts''? I don't understand it because if $a_n = (-1)^n$ it is oscillating between two bounding values but not by diminishing amounts? Also why are these the only two possible cases that can happen when it does not converge?

Comment: The over- resp undershoot diminishes. In the example given by user 18921 in the comment under the question, the two bounding values are $1$ and $-1$, and $a_n=(-1)^n(1+\frac1n)$ over/undershoots by $\frac1n$. $a_n=(-1)^n$ doesn't over or undershoot at all. The point is that you don't necessarily have $\liminf a_n\leqslant a_k\leqslant\limsup a_n$, you can have for example $a_k>\limsup a_n$ for some $k$, but the overshoot $a_k-\limsup a_n$ in such cases converges to $0$. For every $\varepsilon>0$, $\liminf a_n-\varepsilon<a_k<\limsup a_n+\varepsilon$ for all large $k$.

Comment: Thank you. And how can one prove that the only two cases when a sequence is not Cauchy are when it is unbounded or when it is oscillating?

Comment: If the sequence is bounded, it has finite $\liminf a_n$ and $\limsup a_n$. The sequence converges if and only if $L := \liminf a_n = \limsup a_n =: U$. If $L < U$, let $\varepsilon = (U-L)/20$. By definition of $\liminf$ and $\limsup$, there are infinitely many $a_n$ within $\varepsilon$ of $L$, and also infinitely many within $\varepsilon$ of $U$. So after each term close to $L$, there is a next term close to $U$ and vice versa. So it goes up and down, and up, and down... It may wiggle in between. The oscillations need not be regular, almost periodic or anything, but the sequence must go from

Comment: close to one point to close to the other infinitely often. That's what I called "oscillate". It follows almost directly from the definitions of $\liminf$ and $\limsup$, with the assumption that the sequence doesn't converge.